# Why is an empty Merge Commit being Produced

Tags: git, github

Dev wants to update featureBranch with updated changes from origin/master branch, and then push their local changes to origin/featureBranch

```
git checkout featureBranch
git add .
git commit -n -m "message"
git checkout master
git fetch
git checkout featureBranch
git merge master --no-verify
git push origin featureBranch
```

I see a completely blank commit (merging with dev), with 0 additions and 0 removals.  Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not enough information in the question to say *exactly* why you got a merge commit, but there are several possibilities:

- A merge commit is necessary.  This occurs if the two branch-tip commits are both ahead of the shared (common) merge base commit.  That can happen even if there are no *changes* involved in making the merge.
- A merge commit was forced.  That happens with GitHub's <kbd>MERGE</kbd> button always, and with command-line Git, happens if you specify the `--no-ff` option.  You can include this option in your configuration, in which case we would not see it on the command line.
- A fast-forward was *possible* but the argument to `git merge` was that of a *tag* and the tag:

  > is not stored in its natural place in the `refs/tags/` hierarchy

  (as described in [the `git merge` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge), under the `--ff`, `--no-ff`, `--ff-only` options).

(in decreasing order of probability).  The last would require that the name `master` be resolved to a tag object, which is pretty unlikely but not technically impossible.  The middle would occur if you configured `merge.ff` to `false`.  The first is the most likely as it is quite common.

> I see a completely blank commit (merging with dev), with 0 additions and 0 removals.  Why?

No commit is ever *blank* (nor empty, despite the `git commit --allow-empty` option spelling).  A commit always contains:

- a full snapshot of every file (with the usual compression and de-duplication), plus
- metadata.

A *merge commit* contains metadata listing two or more parent hash IDs: that's what makes it a merge commit in the first place.  An ordinary (non-merge) commit has one parent, and at least one commit in every non-empty repository is the very first commit and therefore has *no* parent, making it a (usually *the*) *root commit*.  Every commit also has a full snapshot of every file: merge commits are no different here.

Suppose we have the following series of commits, and two branch names `br1` and `br2` selecting their tip commits:

```
          I--J   <-- br1
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- br2
```

Running:

```
git checkout br1 && git merge br2
```

will, if all goes well, produce the new merge commit `M` on branch `br1` and leave us with:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L   <-- br2
```

The *snapshot* for commit `M` is that made by:

- finding the differences (various files changes) from `H` to `J`;
- finding the differences from `H` to `L` as well;
- *combining* (merging) those *differences*; and
- applying the combined differences to the snapshot from commit `H`.

This keeps the `H`-to-`J` changes and adds the `H`-to-`L` changes, if you like to view it that way, or it keeps the `H`-to-`L` changes and adds the `H`-to-`J` changes: sums are (at least for non-conflict cases) commutative, like integer arithmetic: 3 + 7 = 10, but 7 + 3 = 10 too.

If whoever made the `br2` changes copied exactly the `br1` changes, the "sum" that Git makes here will be to keep just *one copy* of the changes.  So the snapshot in `M` will match *both* of those in `J` *and* `L` (which themselves both match).  That would show as no additions and no removals.

If whoever made one of the two branches made a change, then reverted it, so that the snapshot in one of `J` or `L` matched the snapshot in `H`, that "side" of the merge would have no contribution, and the snapshot in `M` would match the other commit.  If the "side" that had a net-zero contribution was `br2`, that too would show as no additions and no removals.

Without more (e.g., the output from `git log --graph`, perhaps with `--oneline`, and/or the results of `git merge-base` from before the merge plus the appropriate `git diff` commands to see what changes Git is merging, and/or the result of `git config --get merge.ff`) we can't say which of these might have triggered the "empty" merge (to misuse the word "empty" the way Git does).